# cross browsers jquery animate scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I'm facing a problem with jquery animate scrollTop to a defined div.

I use this code to animate the scroll:

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop: $('#sections_display').offset().top-100}, 500, function(){
    $('#ajax_load').load('file.php');
});
```

But this don't work in Firefox or in IE.

And when i use `$('html').animate` instead of `$('body').animate` it don't work in Chrome.

I tried also to use the both: `$('html,body').animate` but the problem is the callback function `$('#ajax_load').load('file.php');` is executed double times and this call the file 2 times.

I temporary solved the problem by using **php** but this solution forced me to repeat code 2 times in every page to make 2 arrays of browsers which support `$('body').animate` and `$('html').animate`.

I searched here and found this: [jquery animate scrolltop callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206738/jquery-animate-scrolltop-callback) But didn't work.

I also tried:

`$(window).animate`

`$(document).animate`

`$('#container-div').animate`

But no way to achieve this.

Can i find a cross browser method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacky solution might do the trick...

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#sections_display').offset().top-100}, 500);

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#ajax_load').load('file.php');
}, 500);
```

Comment: delay(500) didn't has any effect, i don't know why?
I tested delay(10000) but the same result "no delay"

Comment: Himm... yes looks like the load() method won't queue, but I have added another solution to my answer which should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-animate-scrolltop-12-1-2010#14737000000412227)

> It won't work on all major browsers. Not all of them support scrolling when applied to 'html', some require 'body'. This varies depending on whether you're on quirks mode or not. It's even more problematic when animating iframes

The topic starter ended up applying the animate to `html,body` instead of one another.

Comment: Yes, i read this post , but i decided to search and ask to know if there is any hack for it